# Tracelog/Powershell_command --> Which is more accurate for finding utilization of each cpu logical processor?

Tags: powershell, cpu, utilization, trace-logging

The methods are described below.

Method 1:
Run a tracelog session (tracelog is a command-line utility in Windows operating systems which collects and views log data), get log data, find idle time of each logical processor, calculate utilization.

Method 2:
Use powershell command - "\Processor Information(*)% Processor Utility" which prints utilization of each logical processor. These values match with those of task manager.

I would like to know which of the above methods is more accurate ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `tracelog` requires the WDK (Windows Driver Kit) to be installed. Please show a working PowerShell command.